# Oracle Apex, Master detail with adjustable sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Oracle 11g
Apex 4.2

HI guys

I have a master / detail table, however I’m trying to apply a sequence to the detail section.

Master table contains

M_ID,  DATE, PER_ID

1, 01-May-15, 1

2, 01-May-15, 2

Detail

D_ID,  M_ID(FK), SEQ, ACCOUNT_ID, TASK_ID, HRS, TRAVEL_HRS

The sequence needs to increase each time a job is requested/created, however have the ability to change its order. For Each job this must start from 1.

Once the SEQ is set. I will then need to go update all current records retrospectively .

so tables would look something like

[image]

As you can see, the SEQ increases for each detail record.

The user can update the detail table via different methods. However the primary way is via a tabular form. So when a user creates a new row within the detail form this needs to increment the SEQ by one. However the user may wish to change the SEQ or order.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: added  image of table

Comment: What do you mean by " each time a job is requested/created"? Is this done by a user, by some script? What is going on in your application?

Comment: @Rene The user can update the detail table via different methods. However the primary way is via a tabular form. So when a user creates a new row within the detail form this needs to increment the SEQ by one. However the user may wish to change the SEQ or order.

Comment: May be just add TRIGGER before insert, and set value of new column to select MAX(SEQ)+1 from Detail where M_ID = XXX?  Is this SEQ number must be unique for rows with equal M_ID? If must be unique, you must also add check before edit this column.